# Sign change in Newton's Method lecture example unclear

Tags: numerical-methods

In an example in my lecture notes there's a sign change at one of the steps. I assume find our $f(x)$ to compute the zeroes of our $g(x)$ and I have no idea why it happened.

Newton's method for computer $\sqrt2$ , i.e for computing a zero of:

$$g(x) = x^2 -2$$

is given by

$$x_{k+1} = x_k - \frac{x_k^2 -2}{2x_k}$$

that is,

$$x_{k+1} = \frac{x_k^2 +2}{2x_k}$$

that is,

$$x_{k+1} = f(x_k)$$

where

$$f(x) =\frac{x^2 +2}{2x}.$$

I'm just not sure even in the context of the rest of my notes where that sign change comes from, at the first "that is,", not without at least changing the $x_k$'s sign.

Comment: Not in particular, I'm just repeating the page exactly from my professor's slides and there's a sign change (-2 to +2) that I don't understand.

Comment: I'm not 100% who to direct this to, but as for the subscript vs superscript notation I am just abiding by the format used in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of algebra.  I'm going to call $x^{(k)}$ '$y$' and $x^{(k+1)}$ '$z$' to make this clearer.  Then you have $$\begin{align}
z&=y-\frac{y^2-2}{2y} \\
&=y\cdot\frac{2y}{2y}-\frac{y^2-2}{2y} \\
&=\frac{2y^2}{2y}-\frac{y^2-2}{2y}\\
&=\frac{(2y^2)-(y^2-2)}{2y}\\
&=\frac{2y^2-y^2+2}{2y}\\
&=\frac{y^2+2}{2y}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Argh, I thought it was this but when I tried to do it in my head, ack. I need to try everything on paper at least once. Accepting answer in t minus 3 minutes.